# How can I render a function on a stateless component just below another component within a conditional?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

I have a stateless component where I am using a conditional to render some components:

```
      <div className="bx--col-md-12 bx--offset-xxl-1 bx--col-xxl-10">
        {softlayerAccountId ? (
          <TableToolbarComp />
          renderComponents()
        ) : (
          <div className="login-settings__message">
            <UpgradeMessage />
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
```

When `<TableToolbarComp />` and `renderComponents()` were not inside the conditional, it was working good, but now it is throwing a parsing error message.

What can I do?

Error:

```
>SyntaxError: /Users/marceloretana/Documents/forks/billing/src/client/pages/Cancellations/index.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (82:14)

  80 |             {softlayerAccountId ? (
  81 |               <TableToolbarComp />
> 82 |               renderComponents()
     |               ^
  83 |             ) : (
  84 |               <div className="login-settings__message">
  85 |                 <UpgradeMessage />
```

Even if I set `{}` around `renderComponents()` I get this

```
SyntaxError: /Users/marceloretana/Documents/forks/billing/src/client/pages/Cancellations/index.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (82:14)

  80 |             {softlayerAccountId ? (
  81 |               <TableToolbarComp />
> 82 |               { renderComponents() }
     |               ^
  83 |             ) : (
```

Comment: What is the error message you're getting?

Comment: You don't say what the error message is, but I know you can't put a function call after a JSX tag like that; it's a syntax error.

Comment: @dan see update on the post

Comment: What is in the `renderComponents()` function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `()` is the grouping operator, and you cannot write both JSX and plain JS in the same group. The JS (`renderComponents()`) has to be escaped using curly braces `{}`. Furthermore, you cannot return multiple containing elements from the group, so you either have to wrap it in a containing element (i.e. a `div`) or if you don't want additional markup, you can use [React.Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html):

```
 <div className="bx--col-md-12 bx--offset-xxl-1 bx--col-xxl-10">
    {softlayerAccountId ? (
      <React.Fragment>
          <TableToolbarComp />
          {renderComponents()}
      </React.Fragment>
    ) : (
      <div className="login-settings__message">
        <UpgradeMessage />
      </div>
    )}
  </div>
```

Comment: I am still getting an error with that syntax: `SyntaxError: /Users/marceloretana/Documents/forks/billing/src/client/pages/Cancellations/index.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (82:14)

  80 |             {softlayerAccountId ? (
  81 |               <TableToolbarComp />
> 82 |               { renderComponents() }
     |               ^
  83 |             ) : (`

Comment: @Reacting Updated my answer, let me know if this works

Comment: `(...)` is the normal [JavaScript grouping operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping). It has nothing to do with React or JSX. You wouldn't be able to write `softlayerAccountId ? (foo() renderComponents()) : (bar())` in "normal JavaScript" either.

Comment: @FelixKling Updated my answer accordingly

Answer (score 2):

you need wrapper in react component content like this

```
  <div className="bx--col-md-12 bx--offset-xxl-1 bx--col-xxl-10">
        {softlayerAccountId ? (
          <div>
            <TableToolbarComp />
             {renderComponents()}
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div className="login-settings__message">
            <UpgradeMessage />
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
```

you always need return one element